# Is there a good solution for managing website log-in process?

Tags: python, authentication, automation, finance

I am trying to write a program which logs into my online bank and security account and parse savings data from website, similar to web scraping.

**Goal is to gather savings info without opening up browser and login to website .**

Ideally , I was thinking this can be achieved by one of below options .

1. Write python script that imitates browser behavior and parse html .
2. Use central authentication platform, perhaps a *container*, that negotiates with web sites .
3. Similar to *2* but use cloud service

Especially , **option 2** is my preference since maintenance seems to be easy .

```
python <=> auth platform <=> website
```

Would there be any thrid party software (or a library) that can automate login process and then access response with python script ?

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) using Chrome driver with headless option.
I am not sure this is best option but its working.